# Is there a plugin/library that can allow me to make a beautiful scrolling wall?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout, grid

If you go to http://wonderwall.msn.com/, you'll notice that the wall is scrollable...and it's an awesome grid layout.

Is there a library that can do this? Preferably in JQuery

Comment: view their source, they're using the YUI library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript library used on this site was YUI.

Here is a link to there site.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/

Although i dont think there is one plugin that will achieve the total effect. The wonderwall website uses a clever combo of js and good css.